# Creating some sort of SPA using Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, single-page-application

I'm trying to build an SPA using jquery. I have some html (nothing special).

I just have a menu and some divs. Depending on which menu item you click, a specific div should be displayed.

I can use `.show()` and `.hide()` and make use of id's and data-attributes.

But I was wondering if there are better ways to perform this kind of functionality.

Comment: You can add data attributes to the html to indicate where this specific button leads to and goes back to (2 data attribute in that case), then just update your function to use those data attribute values so that the function can be used with any of your divs. There are many ways to do this depending on your html is strucutred

Comment: So instead of using .show on an id i could use .show on a data-attribute. And use .hide on the active data-atrribute div?

Comment: Yes, that's only one way to go about it, you could also have classes on each level so that you can target the classes when opening and closing. Since you will be acting on click, you will know what's clicked and you can get the parent element(s) to do something if need to be

Comment: You posted all unnecessary code and left out the required code(header). I can't see the buttons' html in order to copy and paste it to give you an answer. Can you show the header?

Comment: My suggestion would be to create one function and use it with onClick="function(event)" and pass the event, which you'll use to figure out which button was clicked and then toggle accordingly. This won't required extra attributes to work.

Comment: Definitely don't add onclick to your html, click handling can be done in js, no need to pollute the markup

Comment: I was thinking using the .click function in jquery and use the $(this) on classes to close the current div whenever you click on 'go back '

Comment: Your back button should be displayed or hidden with css, I don't see the need to show it with js since it is in the sub-menu. It's actually quite simple to do what you want, add something like data-target="#weed-menu" and general class to your #menu items, so on click, you would hide #menu, and show `$(data('target')), and when you click back, hide all sub-menu items(use a class for this) and show #menu

Comment: If you need to show a specific menu when pressing back, you can again use the data attribute method, or you could cache the item which brought you to the sub menu and just use that jquery object to show it again

Comment: There's no problem with adding on click. The worst is using it when there's more elements and you have to repeat it for every element. I am going to post an answer now... to demonstrate my reasoning.

Comment: So a data-target on every menu-item button, and class on the connected menu div?

Comment: See my answer, your IDs can be used to connect the items so we can avoid the data attribute method

Comment: Like I always say - no one approach is right, the one that often lasts with the one that makes things easier but adheres to known patterns. The onclick button is there for a reason and that is why in Angular you pretty much rely on it so much. But in this case, it is usable except for when there is more elements and you end up repeating the same thing. I have also posted a simple answer without the onclick="" in the view.

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified your code to the bone to show it easier

Since your ID on the triggers kind of matches your sub-menu, I have used them to target the content. You would put the code in doc ready.

`$( "#" + this.id.replace("-tab", "-menu") )` this line simply uses the clicked ID and replaces the -tab with -menu. This is done to work with your current html

```js
var $menu = $('#menu');
var $subMenu = $('.sub-menu');

$('.menu-item').on("click", function() {
  $menu.hide();

  $( "#" + this.id.replace("-tab", "-menu") ).show();
});

$('.back-btn').on( "click", function() {
  // hide all sub-menu, no need to be specific
  $subMenu.hide();

  $menu.show();      
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="menu">

  <div id="weed-tab" class="menu-item">
    <p class="menu-name">Wiet</p>
  </div>
  <div id="indica-tab" class="menu-item">
    <p class="menu-name">Indica</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid sub-menu" id="weed-menu">weed
  <div class="back-btn">
    back
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid sub-menu" id="indica-menu">indica
  <div class="back-btn">
    back
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the expected result what i want. I'm only not sure if it's 100% correct: https://pastebin.com/17xJa9un

Comment: No, it doesn't work because the checking for object class part is wrong. If you want to ask a different question, then post a different question. if this question is no longer relevant and my answer has not helped you then you can delete this question and ask a different question